# Have textarea act as an Input

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I apply style and javascript to a textarea field to get it to act like an input textfield?

I have some input textfields that I want to capture pastes with newline characters.  To achieve this I converted the input textfields to textareas.  It would be nice however if the textarea input looked and acted like a input field.

I've determined how to size the textarea to look like an input, but there are other subtle differences all of which I haven't inventoried.  I'm looking for a library or comprehensive way to have textarea act like textfield.

Thank you

---

Update

I'm going to leave the text fields alone.  It turns out I can just create a hidden textarea and switch focus to that element on paste events to grab multiline pasted data.

Comment: Are you just looking for the height to be the same as a normal text input?

Comment: If you want to capture input with newlines then you *shouldn't* make them look like text fields; after the paste it won't look like it worked. And enjoy all the pastes from Word documents.

Comment: Dave Newton, I'm capturing the pasted values to flow the tabbed and new-lined data into separate input boxes that are aligned in a grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I've found the follow style html and css useful.

```
textarea {
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
}

<textarea rows=1 wrap=Off></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get it to look like an input field you'd need to change the `length` and `width` of it to be the proper size. Other than that the two look rather similar. As for the JavaScript, it would be similar to what you're already using for the `inputs`.

Comment: Please provide code samples if you like specific styling and such.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the data like this

```
$("#textarea1").val()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

```
textarea{
 width: 10em;  
    height:1.2em;

}
```

for the style